# 2D array to represent a huge python dict, COOrdinate like solution to save memory

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, numba

I try to update a dict_with_tuples_key with the data from an array:

```
myarray = np.array([[0, 0],  # 0, 1
                    [0, 1],
                    [1, 1],  # 1, 2
                    [1, 2],  # 1, 3
                    [2, 2],
                    [1, 3]]
) # a lot of this with shape~(10e6, 2)

dict_with_tuples_key = {(0, 1): 1,
                        (3, 7): 1} # ~10e6 keys
```

Using an array to store the dict values, (thanks to @MSeifert) we get this:

```
def convert_dict_to_darray(dict_with_tuples_key, myarray):
    idx_max_array = np.max(myarray, axis=0)
    idx_max_dict  = np.max(dict_with_tuples_key.keys(), axis=0)
    lens = np.max([list(idx_max_array), list(idx_max_dict)], axis=0)
    xlen, ylen = lens[0] + 1, lens[1] + 1
    darray = np.zeros((xlen, ylen)) # Empty array to hold all indexes in myarray
    for key, value in dict_with_tuples_key.items():
        darray[key] = value
    return darray

@njit
def update_darray(darray, myarray):
    elements = myarray.shape[0]
    for i in range(elements):
        darray[myarray[i][0]][myarray[i][1]] += 1
    return darray

def darray_to_dict(darray):
    updated_dict = {}
    keys = zip(*map(list, np.nonzero(darray)))
    for x, y in keys:
        updated_dict[(x, y)] = darray[x, y]
    return updated_dict

darray = convert_dict_to_darray(dict_with_tuples_key, myarray)
darray = update_darray(darray, myarray)
```

I get the exact result needed:

```
# print darray_to_dict(darray)
# {(0, 1): 2.0,
#  (0, 0): 1.0,
#  (1, 1): 1.0,
#  (2, 2): 1.0,
#  (1, 2): 1.0,
#  (1, 3): 1.0,
#  (3, 7): 1.0, }
```

For small matrix it work quit well, @njit work on it so it's very fast,
but...

the creation of the huge empty `darray = np.zeros((xlen, ylen))` **does not fit on memory**. How can we avoid to assign a very sparse array, and only store non null values like sparse matrix in COOrdinate format ?

Comment: Could you specify how big ``xlen`` and ``ylen`` are?

Comment: Also maybe neither a dict nor a np.ndarray are the ideal containers for this task. Have you considered [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)? But that depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: I came from pandas, as far as I know there is no COOrdinate, storage for pandas, pandas store in int64 numpy arrays. And as soon as I make this fit in memory I will have to make it parallel. We are close, if we can"guess" the number of non zero of the darray matrix. The matrix is big np.zeros([int(200e3), int(150e3)]) but very sparse probably 20e6 non zeros values.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dok_matrix` from `scipy`; a `dock_matrix` is a dictionary Of Keys based sparse matrix. They allow you to build sparse matrices incrementally and they won't allocate huge empty `darray = np.zeros((xlen, ylen))` that does not fit into your computer memory.

The only change to do is to import the right module from scipy and to change the definition of `darray` in your function `convert_dict_to_darray`.

It will look like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

def convert_dict_to_darray(dict_with_tuples_key, myarray):
    idx_max_array = np.max(myarray, axis=0)
    idx_max_dict  = np.max(dict_with_tuples_key.keys(), axis=0)
    lens = np.max([list(idx_max_array), list(idx_max_dict)], axis=0)
    xlen, ylen = lens[0] + 1, lens[1] + 1
    darray = dok_matrix( (xlen, ylen) )
    for key, value in dict_with_tuples_key.items():
        darray[key[0], key[1]] = value
    return darray
```

Comment: If `key` is already a `tuple` of two elements, then doing `darray[key[0], key[1]]` is just a silly way to unpack and repack the same `tuple`; could just do `darray[key]`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, you are  right. I will let the OP do that if he likes the suggestion. I wanted to suggest the least possible change to what he already did.